# Cannot Access the Local Host on Python 127.0.0.1:8000 in browser

Tags: python, browser, path, pycharm, localhost

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/'),include('products.urls') #this line
]
```

Hi,anyone. sorry to ask this kind of question but this my first time tryin' python.
Whats wrong with `path('products/'),include('products.urls')` ?
if i delete that line, i can run the local host in http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in my tutorial explain to add that line to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/products to show Hello World in browser, but if i ad that line, the result on me is problem loading page. With this error shown in terminal:

```
  File "C:\Users\BinarK\PycharmProjects\PyShop\pyshop\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('products/'),include('products.urls')
TypeError: _path() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR2Tk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I change it to `path('products/', include('products.urls'))`
and the result in the browser is:

> ```
> Page not found (404)
> Request Method:   GET
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/products
> ```
>
> Using the URLconf defined in pyshop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> admin/
> ```
>
> The current path, products, didn't match any of these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

But it still did not run.

I went to Settings and changed the last line from `Debug = True` to `False`, but nothing changed and it was still not able to access the URL.

I am using Windows 11 and Python 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar issue,  I had forgotten to add the following import in the urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

Give that a shot